# C# change property of an object dynamically

Tags: c#, properties

Is there a way to change the property of an object in C# like this.

int Number = 1;

label[Number].Text = "Test";

And the result will change label1.Text to "Test";

Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

You may put all the labels into an array:

```
var labels = new[] { label1, label2, label3, label4 };
```

And then use array indexer:

```
int number = 0;
labels[number].Text = "Test";
```

Comment: Remember that in C# arrays are indexed from 0

Answer (score 3):

Add labels to a List

```
List<Label> list = new List<Label>()
list.Add(label1);
list.Add(label2);

list[0].Text = "Text for label 1";
list[1].Text = "Text for label 2";
```

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the another way, but most likely it's not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dictionary (or associated array) can help you. Where key is integer and value - Label:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Label>();
dictionary[2] = label1;
dictionary[7] = label2;
dictionary[12] = label2;

int number = 2;
dictionary[number].Text = "Test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try FindControl:

```
Label lbl = (Label) FindControl("label" + yourVariableHere);
lbl.Text = "Test";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx